# How to retrieve the array from a db table

Tags: php, mysql

The array in below piece of code populates a dropbox. I want to keep the values in a mysql db table and loop through the table to populate the dropdown, instead of hardcoding every item. Can anyone help me about it?

```
$tableColumns['sektor'] = array(
    'display_text' => 'Sektör', 
    'perms' => 'EVCAXQSFHOT', 
    'val_fun' => array(&$this,'validateFun'), 
        'select_array' => array(
        'Adalet ve Güvenlik' => 'Adalet ve Güvenlik', 
        'Ağaç İşleri, Kağıt ve Kağıt Ürünleri' => 'Ağaç İşleri, Kağıt ve Kağıt Ürünleri', 
        'Bilişim Teknolojileri' => 'Bilişim Teknolojileri', 
        'Cam, Çimento ve Toprak' => 'Cam, Çimento ve Toprak',
        'Çevre' => 'Çevre',
        'Eğitim' => 'Eğitim',
        'Elektrik ve Elektronik' => 'Elektrik ve Elektronik',
        'Enerji' => 'Enerji',
        'Finans' => 'Finans',
        'Gıda' => 'Gıda',
        'İnşaat' => 'İnşaat',
        'İş ve Yönetim' => 'İş ve Yönetim',
        'Kimya, Petrol, Lastik ve Plastik' => 'Kimya, Petrol, Lastik ve Plastik',
        'Kültür, Sanat ve Tasarım' => 'Kültür, Sanat ve Tasarım', 
        'Maden' => 'Maden',
        'Medya, İletişim ve Yayıncılık' => 'Medya, İletişim ve Yayıncılık', 
        'Metal' => 'Metal',
        'Otomotiv' => 'Otomotiv', 
        'Sağlık ve Sosyal Hizmetler' => 'Sağlık ve Sosyal Hizmetler',
        'Spor ve Rekreasyon' => 'Spor ve Rekreasyon',
        'Tarım, Avcılık ve Balıkçılık' => 'Tarım, Avcılık ve Balıkçılık', 
        'Tekstil, Hazır Giyim, Deri' => 'Tekstil, Hazır Giyim, Deri',
        'Ticaret (Satış ve Pazarlama)' => 'Ticaret (Satış ve Pazarlama)',
        'Toplumsal ve Kişisel Hizmetler' => 'Toplumsal ve Kişisel Hizmetler',
        'Turizm, Konaklama, Yiyecek-İçecek Hizmetleri' => 'Turizm, Konaklama, Yiyecek-İçecek Hizmetleri',
        'Ulaştırma, Lojistik ve Haberleşme' => 'Ulaştırma, Lojistik ve Haberleşme',
    )
);
```

Comment: Read your question and ask yourself the question if you would understand your own question when reading it. Your question is unclear see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you wanted to stored array value in mysql database and fetch from it.

1. You can't store  store array in mysql db column.
2. You can convert array in json format first then can stored.
3. Or create new master table and store value into that and then fetch.
4. Create static variable for array and use it.

Choice is yours....
Good luck